# WPF: ContentTemplate.FindName returns "This operation is valid only on elements that have this template applied" - even after the template has loaded

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to create a MarkupExtension that will:

1. Find the DataTemplate/ContentTemplate that the target object is in.
2. Find another object within that same template.
3. Bind a property on the target object to a property on the object found within that template.

The reason for doing this is that I want to be able to use `ElementName` for binding sources inside DataTemplates, which is usually impossible.

I wrote the following MarkupExtension (note: this is a quick first version, I just want this to work and don't care much about elegance or efficiency at this point):

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Markup;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace Speedocs.WPF.MarkupExtensions
{
    public sealed class DataTemplateElementBinding : MarkupExtension
    {
        #region fields

        private FrameworkElement _targetObject;
        private DependencyProperty _targetProperty;
        private ContentPresenter _templatedParent;

        #endregion

        #region properties

        public string ElementName { get; set; }

        public string Path { get; set; }

        #endregion

        #region Overrides of MarkupExtension

        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            var target = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IProvideValueTarget)) as IProvideValueTarget;
            if (target != null)
            {
                if (target.TargetObject.GetType().Name == "SharedDp") return this;

                _targetObject = target.TargetObject as FrameworkElement;
                if (_targetObject == null)
                {
                    return null;
                }

                _targetProperty = target.TargetProperty as DependencyProperty;
                if (_targetObject == null)
                {
                    return null;
                }

                // now that the target object has been loaded, find the requsted element
                // in the DataTemplate that contains this object, and bind the requested property
                // to that element
                _targetObject.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Loaded, (Action) (() =>
                {
                    _templatedParent = _targetObject.TemplatedParent as ContentPresenter;
                    if (_templatedParent == null) return;

                    var sourceObject =
                        _templatedParent.ContentTemplate.FindName(ElementName, _templatedParent);
                    var binding = new Binding(Path) {Source = sourceObject};
                    _targetObject.SetBinding(_targetProperty, binding);
                }));
            }

            return null;
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

What this MarkupExtension does is:

1. If the TargetObject returned from the IProvideValueTarget is a SharedDp, returns the MarkupExtension itself, so that it is called again when the target value loads.
2. When the template is loaded, ProvideValue will be called again.
3. We then get the TemplatedParent from the target object, find the source object within the template using FindName, and bind to it.

The problem is that when I call `_templatedParent.ContentTemplate.FindName(ElementName, _templatedParent);` I get the error

```
This operation is valid only on elements that have this template applied.
```

Now, I know this error, and it doesn't make sense that it appears here, because the template MUST HAVE already loaded at this point... if it hadn't, ProvideValue wouldn't have been called a second time.

As you can see, I also tried calling `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` using `DispatcherPriority.Loaded`, but that hasn't worked.

Please help :-\

Answer (score 0):

You just `BeginInvoke` the action in a `Loaded` priority, but this is not the same as the `Framework.Loaded` event. A `MarkupExtension` will evaluate its value immediately when it's assigned to a property, not only the usual `Control`s, but also the `Template`.

You need to return `this` if your code is running in a `Template`, so that your actual code can be run in real controls. Just add a condition below:

```
if (!(serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IProvideValueTarget)) is IProvideValueTarget service))
{
    return null;
}
// Return this to provide lazy value when it is running in a template.
if (service.TargetObject.GetType().Name.EndsWith("SharedDp"))
{
    return this;
}
```

Actually, the full name of the `TargetObject` type is `System.Windows.SharedDp`. but it's an internal type, so it may be moved to another namespace. I recommend not to use the full name.

Add this condition before your `BeginInvoke`, and it will help you. Also, you'll find that you can remove `BeginInvoke` safely if you add the condition above.

---

This is my running result:

[image: FindName succeeded]

And this is my XAML testing code (I pasted your `MarkupExtension` and changed nothing):

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="system:String">
            <Grid Name="rootGrid">
                <TextBlock Text="{local:DataTemplateElementBinding ElementName=rootGrid, Path=Background}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    xyz
</ListView>
```

Comment: Thanks @walterlv. I actually do have that condition in the original code, as you can see. Anyway, for some unknown reason, it works now, without any changes that I can remember... no direct changes at least. Oh well.

Comment: @user884248 That's interesting! So could you write something to help others that will read your question in the future?